# How to remove "login to reply" from individual comments

Tags: functions, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove or replace the log-in link for comment replies?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52350/how-to-remove-or-replace-the-log-in-link-for-comment-replies)

I want to get rid of the unnecessary "log in to reply" link from every individual comment when a user is logged out. I found the function in the `wp-includes/comments-template.php` but I'm confused on how to edit it out in my functions.pho. I read about 5 questions on here regarding it but most argued against not editing core functions. Is there a safe way to do edit this function without causing any issues on updates?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way: Add if statement checking if user is logged in our not. Then use CSS and add display:none for the DIV in question?